# Keyboard prevents PC from sleeping; how to debug/solve?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, sleep, power-management, logitech-keyboard

My self-assembled PC fails to enter sleep mode. I managed to track it down to my trusty Logitech G15 (v1) keyboard; if I disconnect it or if it replace it with another keyboard, the PC does enter sleep mode.

What can I do to debug further and solve this issue?

What I have tried so far:

- I set the time for switching off the screen to two minutes and for sleep at 5 minutes; the screen goes indeed black after two minutes, but about 2.5 minutes later, it switches back on. Sleep mode is not entered after 5 minutes.
- I set the time for sleeping to two minutes; the PC indeed sleeps after two minutes and doesn't wake up by itself.
- I ran the MCE Standby Tool (http://slicksolutions.eu/), which suggests that when the screen comes back on, that it received a user input event just before.
- I disabled 'allow this device to wake up the computer' for all 5 keyboard devices in my keyboard manager; didn't help.
- I explored all uses of the powercfg command to no effect.

I come to the tentative conclusion that this is not about waking up the PC, but about input events that prevent the PC from sleeping. These events must be in the software-realm, since once the PC sleeps, they do not occur anymore.
It seems as if the keyboard generates 'ghost' input events every ~4.5 minutes, which have no visible effect, save for preventing the computer to sleep.

I like to continue to use this keyboard, but I don't want it to prevent my PC to sleep. What can I do to debug and/or solve this? Are there any tools that can trace or log all events generated by the keyboard?

Note: I have used the same keyboard with previous PCs and they never had this issue. So it seems the issue is with a specific combination of the keyboard with hardware and/or software.

My PC is built around an AMD 3700X processor on an MSI Mortar Max motherboard, running Windows 10.

**Update:**
I tried also the following:

- uninstall Logitech Gaming Software --> still doesn't sleep
- reinstall Logitech Gaming Software --> still doesn't sleep
- use G15 keyboard with laptop (no LGS) --> sleeps fine

So there still seems to be some magical relation between the keyboard and the specific PC.

Comment: If you have the Logitech software installed I would try to uninstall it.

Comment: That keyboard appears to hail from 2008 so a decade old and older than Windows 10. Maybe it is time for a new gaming keyboard.

Comment: Check power management for the keyboard in device manager, un-tick any boxes available, see if the behavior changes.

Comment: @John: yes, it is old, but it still works fine and serves my needs. Logitech doesn't seem to provide keyboards these days with the same amount of programmable keys. Plus, if I can avoid it, I don't want to spend that amount of money.

Comment: @Moab: I already tried that. It didn't have any effect. The boxes are about allowing the device to wake the PC from sleep, but that seems to be a different thing than preventing it from going to sleep.

Comment: @Ramhound: I tried unstalling the Logitech Gaming Software, but the PC still doesn't sleep.

Comment: Have you used a keylogger?  If you haven't and want to try, make sure the source is reputable; they're regularly used by hackers.

Comment: The G15 is actually a USB 1.1 hub with the keyboard, external port, and LCD all connected to it internally. I suspect that the USB drivers are not getting along with the 1.1 device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that the problem was caused by the Aorus Engine program by Gigabyte. There is more reports on the internet of it causing failures of the PC to sleep:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/gigabytegaming/comments/bc4rja/aorus_engine_prevents_system_sleep/
- http://forum.gigabyte.us/thread/6116/aorus-engine-prevents-entering-sleep

I didn't figure out how the relationship with the keybaord works, but after I disabled the Aorus Engine program, the computer enters sleep mode again.